# Two step registration using devise & omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

My rails app uses devise/omniauth to register new users to the site using their linkedin credentials.

I have it working correctly, but I would like to add a second step to the registration process so a new user can select a username and password for the site.

I've tried redirecting users to devise's new_user_registration_url to complete the registration process, but it treats the redirect as if I am attempting to create the new user, and kicks back error messages saying:

> 2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> Password can't be blank
>
> User name can't be blank

Here is my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.encrypted_password.blank? || user.user_name.blank?
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, :validate => false
    else
      if user.persisted?
        flash[:success] = "Signed in!"
        if user.role == "admin"
          sign_in user
          redirect_to admin_path
        else
          sign_in_and_redirect user
        end
      else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
  alias_method :linkedin, :all
```

Does anyone know how I can proceed from here to make this a two step registration process?

Comment: Did you create a RegistrationsController that inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController. Seems to me that's what's missing here. If you did, please edit your question to show that controller.

Comment: I did not. Are there any resources online where I can see an example?

Comment: Sure thing. Let me introduce you to the magical world of Railscasts: **[OmniAuth Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2)**. You may also enjoy **[OmniAuth Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)**. But Part 2 is the one that relates to your question.

Answer (score -1):

The usual way is to make the page that the omniauth callback page have a form on it with username and password. That form posts to an action that creates the actual user.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not really what I am looking to do. The user model already has a user name in it, and I already have it working without a password required. I am trying to create a registration process where users can select their own passwords.